# How can I set routes in angularjs to go from a dynamic route?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

The goal that you want to achieve is to go from the route `/:userId/`
on route `/:userId/details/`. When I am on the `/:userId'` route, the user appears to me. How do I go to `/:userId/details/` after clicking on the user? When manually typing in the browser bar, example '/:userId/details/' is ok.

**user/user.html**

```
<h3>An user!</h3>

<div>
    <div>Name: <a ui-sref="users({ userId: user.id })/albums" href='#' >
                  {{$ctrl.user.name}}
               </a>
    </div>
    <div>Id: {{$ctrl.user.id}}</div>
</div>
```

**user/user.js**

```
let userModule = angular.module('user', [
  uiRouter
])

.config(($stateProvider) => {
  "ngInject";
  $stateProvider
    .state('user', {
      url: '/{userId}/',
      component: 'user',
      resolve: {
          user: function(UserService, $stateParams) {
              return UserService.getUser($stateParams.userId);
          }
      }
    });
})
```

**details-list/details-list.js**

```
.config(($stateProvider) => {
  "ngInject";
  $stateProvider
    .state('detailsList', {
      url: '/{userId}/details',
      component: 'detailsList',
      resolve: {
          albums: function(DetailsListService, $stateParams) {
              return 
  DetailsListService.getAlbums($stateParams.userId);
         }
      }
    });
})

export default detailsListModule;
```

**details-list/details-list.controller.js**

```
class DetailsListController {
    constructor($stateParams) {
      'ngInject'

      this.userId = $stateParams.userId;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the name of the desired state is `detailsList`, use that:

```
<div>Name: a̶ ̶u̶i̶-̶s̶r̶e̶f̶=̶"̶u̶s̶e̶r̶s̶(̶{̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶I̶d̶:̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶r̶.̶i̶d̶ ̶}̶)̶/̶a̶l̶b̶u̶m̶s̶"̶ ̶h̶r̶e̶f̶=̶'̶#̶'̶ 
           <a ui-sref="detailsList({ userId: $ctrl.user.id })" >
              {{$ctrl.user.name}}
           </a>
<div>Id: {{$ctrl.user.id}}</div>
```

For more information, see

[UI-Router Quick Reference - ui-sref](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)